# How Do I overlay MULTIPLE Images in HTML, CSS, And JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have read literally EVERYTHING on google on how to overlay images. But they all are just 2 Images. I am making a game where you can catch creatures, I have my link to my game here:

http://www.developlucca.com/FeatureQuest/app.html

The game works fine. It's just the images just make the page bigger and longer. The page loads with nothing but a person, just wait, creatures will appear and make the page scroll. Please HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set those images to `position: absolute` and also set the container (`#main-content`) to `position: relative`.

Then you can set position of each image via `top/left/right/bottom` properties.

More about CSS positioning on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

Comment: Alright! I think It worked, but the images still make the page scroll.. :(

Comment: Do you set `top` for all of images? when using absolute position, they will not cause page scrolling, but you need to position them all from top.

Comment: Also if you just want to get rid of scrolling, set `overflow: hidden` on the container

Comment: Awesome! I got it!!

Answer (score 2):

If the parent element is position:relative, 
you can overlay images with display:absolute,

Then inside this parent element you can continue to layer images by z-index, z-index will give view priority to the highest index, just like layer levels.
this will allow you to have as many images over each other as you need.
To handle sizing you can use 100% width/height, or overlays you can you overflow:hidden.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. It helped! Thank you so much! :D